# sms to map location

Tags: sms, maps

does anyone know how to extract the location data from a sms? So someone's location could be marked on Google maps.

Basically they'd text a Google voice number: 'team 1: message'. Then it would  email the server with the message and it would pull the lat and long from the sms.

All the info I could get was, It's done using Drupal, the Mailsave and GMap modules, some custom code to extract the lat/lon data from the message, and AQL's SMS to email service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no location data included with standard SMS. This would be a huge privacy problem. You might be able to look up a location for where the number is based, but not live location.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a way to do this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1967-Cell-Phones-SMS-Twilio-Pusher-ColdFusion-And-Google-Maps-Fun.htm without cold fusion and twilio?

Or are there any tags you can include with a text to send the towers location?